# Depletion P-channel JFET that's saturated at \$V_{GS}=0V\$

Tags: transistors, jfet, fet

Is there any depletion-mode P-channel JFET that is saturated at \$V_{GS} = 0V\$?

Comment: Yeah, all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All JFETs are 'depletion mode' so it's redundant to specify it (if they were not then the gate junction would need to be forward-biased to turn them on).

If Vgs is 0 you'll get a  more-or-less constant current of about Idss for a few volts or more Vgs (up to the breakdown voltage). That's saturation mode.

For much lower currents than Idss, the FET is in the ohmic region with Vgs=0V so it behaves like a resistor. See the below [graph](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/What-is-the-saturation-region-of-a-FET-transistor) (signs different for a p-channel, but the characteristic curves are similar).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From your question I suspect you are missing something about JFETs structure or operation.

JFETs are implicitly depletion-mode devices, i.e. there are no "enhancement" JFETs. At \$V_{GS}=0V\$ *any* JFET (P- or N-channel) will be heavily conducting, since a channel is already formed (depletion-mode). The only difference between the two polarities is that the channel is "filled" with different type of charges (holes for P-channel, electrons for N-channel).

Here you can see the output characteristics of a common through-hole P-channel JFET (J176):

[image]

The top curve corresponds to 0V gate-source voltage. J176 is designed for switching applications, so its characteristics are plotted for relatively low values of \$V_{DS}\$. A P-channel JFET for linear applications is the MMBF5460:

[image]

again the top curve is for \$V_{GS}=0V\$.

You can see, especially in the second example, that for sufficiently high values of \$\left|V_{DS}\right|\$ the device enters saturation, i.e. the drain current becomes almost independent from \$V_{DS}\$ (the curve becomes nearly horizontal).

In summary, the device can be saturated if operated with high enough \$V_{DS}\$. In particular the condition to be saturated would be:

\[
\left|V_{DS}\right| > \left|V_{GS} - V_{GS(off)} \right|
\]

where \$V_{GS(off)}\$ is found in the datasheet.

Comment: Alright... In my defense, the reason I thought there were hardly any "Depletion" P JFET is that I looked over Digikey's list of P JFETs and found in "Current - Drain (Idss) @ Vds (Vgs=0)" tab and the highest current was 20mA. So I thought to myself, this can possibly be Depletion Mode. Also when I looked at "Resistance - RDS(On)", which I take to be the lowest resistance a JFET could operate is 75ohms.

Comment: Are there really no P JFETs that can go at much, much lower impedances?

Comment: @DonutCloseDizAccount Why do you need a JFET with such a low impedance? Usually very low impedances are useful when using the part as a switch to drive heavy loads. In such cases you are better off with a power-MOSFET (there are models with Rds(on) in the milliohm range!)

Comment: Guess I'm back to using a Depletion NMOS pulled up by a resistor and then switched to ground by a BJT. I thought using a "Depletion" P JFET would be a reliable choice, specially if I have no experience in this application area. Even tried to model a BJT perfectly just so I can max out the current for pulling down the Dep NMOS.

Comment: You're right, I should just stick with power MOSFETs.

Comment: #the very first comment: "So I thought to myself, this [CAN'T] possibly be Depletion Mode"

Comment: @DonutCloseDizAccount What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? If you state it directly upfront (in another question) you may get better answers.

Comment: @DonutCloseDizAccount BTW, Your profile shows that you never accepted an answer for any of your question. If you don't know what I mean, read this [help topic](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Accepting answers that helped you not only encourages other people to answer your next question, but improves the site.